# OpenDatabase Error after modifying existing database in Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I'm getting an openDatabase error while trying to modify my existing SQLITE database in Flutter.

I altered an existing table and created a new table.

But the error appears before it executes my onUpgrade callback.

The error appears while executing openDatabase

Error:

> SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(Cannot perform this
> operation because there is no current transaction.) sql 'COMMIT' args
> []})

```
  static Future<Database> initDatabase([int dbVersion]) async {
    return await openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), _dbName),
        version: 2, onUpgrade: _onUpgrade, onCreate: _onCreate);
  }
```

When I change the parameter "version" of openDatabase to 1, the SQL Error doesn't appear anymore. But then I can't get into the onUpgrade callback.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the database is newly created onCreate is called with the databse version (here 2).

The database version is saved to the database, the next time the database is opened and it exists the version is checked.
If the Version of your database is >= the version given in the constructor no onUpgrade is called (and no onCreate since the database already exists, no matter which version).

If you set the version to 1 after it was created onUpgrade is not called since your version is already 2.

The standard procedure is as following:

Start with Database Version 1, the basic create scripts (and scripts to prefill data) are executed in onCreate.

Everytime you have to change the database (new tables, new values, modify tables, etc.) you increase the database version by 1 and implement the change scripts on onUpgrade for the given version.

Here an example about how the methods are called, let's say the app is published with a given Version 2:

App is installed and started for the first time, database does not exist:
onCreate is called with version 2, you have to execute all create and update scripts from initial until version 2.

Now you set the database version to 3 and next time the app starts:
onUpgrade with old Version 2 and new Version 3 is called, you have to execute update scripts for version 3.

I would create a list of scripts to be run per version and iterate over it in onCreate from 1 to the given version and in onUpgrade from oldVersion+1 to newVersion.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you modify your database table you have to uninstall your app and then run your project because table is already created in your local db when you first execute your app and when you modify your code it matches your query with the table you first created